# Некоpректно работает getExternalFilesDir

Tags: android

Я скачиваю файл, устанавливаю его.

После удаляю. После опять скачиваю, и получается, что этот файл якобы остался. Но я его удалил. В чём может быть проблема? И как удалить его полностью?

---

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byteArrayOutputStream.write(HttpRequest.get(str).getResponse().getResponseBytes());
file = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("Download");
outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
fos.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

Comment: Так файл удалился по факту или нет? Если нет, то как Вы его удаляете?

Comment: Да удалился. Проблема была в SD карте